# Dropdown from DB with first option empty

Tags: php, html

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(city) FROM contacts"); 
    echo 
       '<select name="city">'; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo 
       '<option value="'.$row['city'].'">'.$row['city'].'</option>';
    }
    echo 
        '</select> <br />';
```

This pice of code show all cities from my database. 
By default, the first city is selected. I would like that the first option to be something like "Select City" with no value.

How do you think that I could do that in this context?

Comment: after echo '<select name="city">';  write <option value="0">Select City</option>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an option tag before your while loop

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(city) FROM contacts"); 
echo 
   '<select name="city">'; 
echo
   '<option value="">Select City</option>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo 
   '<option value="'.$row['city'].'">'.$row['city'].'</option>';
}
echo 
    '</select> <br />';
```